# Where to get Google Chrome 12 for Linux i386?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, download

I need a .deb download of Google Chrome 12 (not the newest version, but version 12) for i386 Linux. Where can I get it?

I need this version because my operating system doesn't have the libraries required by newer Chrome .deb packages.

In this question I am not interested in upgrading or changing my operating system, and I'm not interested in using different browsers, and I'm aware of the security implications of using that particular old browser. Please give me a working download link if you know one.

Comment: Which OS do you have? Debs for some distributions may be problematic on others.

Comment: I have Ubuntu Karmic. But don't worry about this, just give me a download link to i386 .deb of Google Chrome 12. I expect it to work on with Ubuntu Karmic.

Comment: I have the same problem, I have a ubuntu 8.04 machine and I'd like to get version 12, which is the latest supported by 8.04. Cannot find it anywhere...